# How can i use the query to get the output with comma seperator in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a table like the following:

[image]

I want the output as,

[image]

I am using this query:

```
select Round(Rate,2), Amount from TT_Table;
```

when i give this, it will give precision for the floating point numbers only. it doesnt give precision to the integers. And how i can use the comma seperator to the Amount?

Can anyone please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please, try

```
select to_char(rate, '999.99'), to_char(amount, '999,999,999,999,999') from tt_table
```